# How can I execute a script that runs within an xterm/xgterm?

Tags: shell

I have a script which needs to be executed in xterm or xgterm.

I have to open xterm/xgterm first, then run the script.

How to combine the two steps above and finish it in one script?

Comment: BTW, what is `xgterm`? Are you sure it is not a typo....

Comment: Also, on which operating system are you running?

Comment: Why does that script need to run in a special terminal emulator? Could it be that you actually need it to run in a special shell (bash, zsh, ksh, csh, …)?

Comment: xgterm is not wildly used. You can see it as xterm. The system is fedora20. I have revised the title.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-e` argument to `xterm`. For example to run `ping -c5 localhost` in an xterm window:

```
xterm -e 'ping -c5 localhost'
```

Note that you will have to have the `DISPLAY` environment variable set (to reference a running X server) for this to work.

If you need the xterm session to remain displayed after the command has finished, you could add a sleep:

```
xterm -e 'ping -c5 localhost; sleep 10'
```

- so that the window is displayed for 10 seconds after completion. Or:

```
xterm -e 'ping -c5 localhost; read'
```

- so that the window is displayed until Enter is pressed.